# .sh file opens with emacs instead of running

Tags: .sh

I installed Android studio, and this program starts from the studio.sh file. If I run it from the terminal it goes well, but if I double click on it, this file is opened with emacs. Why?

Answer (score 2):

To run studio.sh file on nautilus,you need to create a .desktop file as below.

Filename : studio.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Run script
Exec='/fullpath_to_script/studio.sh'
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true 
Encoding=UTF-8
```

place the studio.desktop file on desktop.On double click on this file,you will be able to execute *androidstudio.sh* file from nautilus.

You have to give execute permission to studio.desktop file inorder to run,

```
sudo chmod a+x /path/to/studio.desktop
```

Comment: the error risen is:
The application launcher “studio.desktop” has not been marked as trusted. If you do not know the source of this file, launching it may be unsafe.

Comment: i updated my answer.

Comment: now it says `There was an error launching the application` without other explaination

Answer (score 0):

Why? Because of:

[image: Nautilus preferences]

So, when you are in Nautilus, go to **Files** → **Preferences**, select **Behavior** tab and where is **Executable Text Files** field select **Ask each time**, or simple **Run executable text files when they are opened**.